# Debugging .NET web application runs into Access Denied errors

Tags: .net, iis

I'm trying to debug a .NET web service. Since the web service is consumed by an iOS app, I need to be able to access it from an iOS device or a simulator, which are both outside of the local machine.

If I run Visual Studio on a Windows machine and use the default method of "IIS Express", the web service runs but I'm unable to access it from anywhere other than localhost. I assume this is a built-in limitation of IIS Express.

I installed IIS on my Windows machine and switched the project over to "Local IIS", which required me to restart Visual Studio as an Administrator. Now the service runs and can be accessed externally to the machine, but it frequently crashes with Access Denied error messages. For example, this happens any time I try to log anything or open a local file. I don't know how to fix the problem. Should I give the IIS user full control of my home directory (where the project is located)? How do I do that?

Frank

Comment: The actual error page itself talks most of the info. If you don't have a full screenshot attached, there isn't much to discuss.

Comment: No, you shouldn't give IIS full control.   You should though provide the error message as Lex mentions